# CFWheels Pagination using AJAX

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, pagination, cfwheels

I've searched the entire Internet, all of it, and cannot find an answer to this.

I'm using the ColdFusion CFWheels Framework to query a database. The query is done via AJAX like this:

```
var id = $("#ship-id").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/my-controller/my-method?format=json",
    data: {shipId: id},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

        var resultHtml = '';

        $.each(response, function(i, value) {
            resultHtml += '<tr><td>' + value.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + value.LASTNAME + '</td></tr>';
        });

        $("#my-table").html(resultHtml);
    }
});
```

I need to paginate that result set. In CFWheels you normally do that by setting the handle, page, perPage and order values in the query like this:

```
var order = model("order").findAll(
    select="id, firstname, lastname, email",
    where="orderid IN (#ValueList(orders.id)#)",
    handle="ordersQuery",
    page=params.page, 
    perPage=5, 
    order="lastname"
);
```

Then you just put this line in your view:

```
<cfoutput>#paginationLinks(handle="ordersQuery")#</cfoutput>
```

But... how in the heck can you get pagination to work with an AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that something along these lines might be your answer (notice I removed the `url` and added those params to `data`  ...

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        shipId: id,
        controller: myController,
        action: myAction,
        page: params.page,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {

        var resultHtml = '';

        $.each(response, function(i, value) {
            resultHtml += '<tr><td>' + value.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + value.LASTNAME + '</td></tr>';
        });

        $("#my-table").html(resultHtml);
    }
  });
```